# Mongoose: Updation of root data attribute with sum of object array through findOneAndUpdate query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update one of the array elements in a mongo collection using the Node mongoose lib. Here is how my mongo schema looks like:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f8a94ccc8452643f1498419"),
    "private": false,
    "score": 2000,
    "questions": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("5f8a94e8c8452643f149841c"),
        "order": 1,
        "category": "TEXT",
        "definition": "about us",
        "score": 1,
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f8a94e8c8452643f149841d"),
        "order": 2,
        "category": "HTML",
        "definition": "about us",
        "score": 0.5
    }]
}
```

I'm updating the score inside the question array, the score attribute at the root array to be updated which is the sum of the array score i.e.

```
root score => question array1.score + array2.score
```

I used below mongoose function:

```
  Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: id,
      "questions._id": qid,
    },
    {
     '$set': {
          'questions.$.order': 1,
          'questions.$.score': 1,
          'questions.$.type': 'HTML',
          '$sum': { 'score': 'questions.score' }
      }
    })
```

While all other attributes are getting updated, *the root score is never getting updated*.

> Note: that, ***$setoninsert*** is not an option as in this case, **upsert** is always **false**.

Is this at all possible to perform both of this updates using a *single query*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$set` to update matching question that id matches with `qid`
- `$set` to update root score from score of `questions` array

```
let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f8a94ccc8452643f1498419");
let qid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f8a94e8c8452643f149841c");
let question = {
  score: 1,
  order: 1,
  category: "TEXT"
};

Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: id },
  [{
    $set: {
      questions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$questions",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this._id", qid] },
                  question, // add update fields in object
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      score: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$questions",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: ["$$value", "$$this.score"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CyBig6tetIL)

Comment: It works. Thanks a ton dude...you just made my day :)