# Mongoose: Updation of parent-child data attribute with sum of nested object array through findOneAndUpdate query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update one of the **nested array elements** in a mongo collection using the Node mongoose lib. Here is how my mongo schema looks like:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af2fc5f23667adf3bbaf2"),
    "score": 2.5,
    "questions": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5f8af30d5f23667adf3bbaf5"),
            "score": 1.5,
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf8"),
            "score": 1,
            "options": [{
                    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbaf9"),
                    "score": 1,
                    "desc": "description 1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbafa"),
                    "score": 0,
                    "desc": "description 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm updating the score inside the question array, the score attribute at the root array to be updated which is the sum of the array score i.e.

```
root score => question array1.score + array2.score
question score => option array1.score + array2.score
```

I used below mongoose function as mentioned in this answer by [@turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal) which is working fine to update the root score based onn question array:

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401747/3159714**

Point to note here that, some other attributes like **desc** in the option array also needs to be updated in the same call.

> Note: that, ***$setoninsert*** is not an option as in this case, **upsert** is always **false**.

Is this at all possible to perform both of this updates using a *single query*?

Comment: For which option out of two? is there any input _id for specific option?

Comment: For reference, I need to update option id 5f8af3115f23667adf3bbafa

Comment: Okay, can you explain more, it will be always one option for update or multiple or whole array of options, and also will it be just `desc` field only or more fields?, why i am asking because i can suggest better solution.

Comment: At a time only one option can be udated and any of the attribute in that element can be updated; for reference, lets consider I want to update the desc and score. So the score at the root level and the corrresponnding score at the question level should be refreshed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add one more `$map` for options array check condition if option _id match then update option object and merge with current object using `$mergeObjects`

```
let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f8a94ccc8452643f1498419");

let oid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f8af3115f23667adf3bbafa");
let option = {
  desc: "updated desc"
};

let qid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f8a94e8c8452643f149841c");
let question = {
  score: 1,
  order: 1,
  category: "TEXT",
  options: {
    $map: {
      input: "$$this.options",
      in: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$this",
          { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this._id", oid] }, option, {}] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};

Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: id },
  [{
    $set: {
      questions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$questions",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this._id", qid] }, question, {}] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      score: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$questions",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: ["$$value", "$$this.score"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pTk4dSp1fQ2)

Comment: Thanks a lot...orking like a charm :)

Comment: One question...if i want to just update the desc of a particular option wwithout impacting any other attribute, what query should I use? removing the last $set fromt he above query can't be use i that case

Comment: Tried this

[
      {
        $set: {
          questions: {
            $map: {
              input: "$questions",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this.options",
                  {
                    $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this._id", ObjectId(oid)] }, {"desc" : "xyx"}, {}],
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }
    ]

But doesnt work

Comment: just use arrayFilters like this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QOuW9wzoSBi)